# I want to retrieve the usersinfo of the current user in Box API v2 for Android

Tags: android, box-api

Please help me in getting the user details for the current user in the BoxApi v2 for android

The code which I am using the user details is as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        BoxAndroidClient client = null;
        if (Activity.RESULT_OK != AUTH_REQUEST) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            BoxAndroidOAuthData oauth = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(OAuthActivity.BOX_CLIENT_OAUTH);

            BoxAndroidOAuthData moath = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(OAuthActivity.USER_SERVICE);
            client = new BoxAndroidClient(HelloWorldApplication.CLIENT_ID,
                    HelloWorldApplication.CLIENT_SECRET, null, null);
            client.authenticate(oauth);

            accestoken = oauth.getAccessToken().toString();
            System.out.println("AUTHDATA" + oauth.getAccessToken().toString());// client.getUsersManager().getCurrentUser(requestObj).toString()
            // + oauth.getAccessToken().toString());
            BoxUser user = new BoxUser();
            System.out.println("ID" + user.getId());
            if (client == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                ((HelloWorldApplication) getApplication()).setClient(client);
                Toast.makeText(this, "authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject = null;
        List<BoxUser> userList = null;
        try {
            userList = client.getUsersManager().getAllEnterpriseUser(
                    requestObject, null);
        } catch (BoxRestException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BoxServerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AuthFatalFailureException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (BoxUser usr : userList) {
            System.out.println("Addr: " + usr.getAddress());
            System.out.println("Name : " + usr.getName());
            System.out.println("Login : " + usr.getLogin());
        }

    }
```

I am getting the exception as networkonmainthreadexception...
Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Getting current user info in the raw api is done with a call to GET /users/me

Not sure what that looks like in the Java, but probably something more like :

```
user = client.getUsersManager().getCurrentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your access token is up to date. Also, looking at your code, why have you set

```
BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject = null;
```

Instead do:

```
BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject = new BoxDefaultRequestObject()
```

Otherwise the box library will get a null pointer exception. It gets the JSON parser from the request object.

Let me know if this works.